# Align imageview vertically center in tablerow

Tags: java, android, row, android-imageview, android-tablelayout

I have created a dynamic table. The table is supposed to have a row in which there will be an imageview in the extreme left, a textview in the middle and a checkbox in the extreme right. All the controls are showing up. The textview and the checkbox is also vertically centered, but the inageview could not be centered, thus, the row looks bad. **I want to put the imageview in a line with the textview and the checkbox.**

[image: output which I am getting]

The above image shows the output which I am getting right now. I want the blue arrow to come in line with the textview and the checkbox.

**The source code of the activity:**

```
public class CalendarActivity extends Activity {

    TableLayout first_calendar_table;
    TableRow first_calendar_tr_data;
    int tableRowCount = 0;
    boolean showingFirst = true;

    String chkChecked = "false";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_calendar);

        first_calendar_table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.first_calendar_table);

        tableHeads();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.calendar, menu);
        return true;
    }

    // method to generate table heads
    public void tableHeads() {

        // ---------------Calendar Table
        // Header-----------------------------------------------
        TableRow supplier_details_tr_head = new TableRow(this);
        supplier_details_tr_head.setId(10);
        supplier_details_tr_head.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_header);
        supplier_details_tr_head.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        // ImageView Setup
        final ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
        // setting image resource
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.closed_icon);
        imageView.setId(20);
        //imageView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        // adding view to layout
        supplier_details_tr_head.addView(imageView);

        TextView select_head = new TextView(this);
        select_head.setId(20);
        select_head.setText(Html.fromHtml("2014-2015"));
        select_head.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        select_head.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        select_head.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        supplier_details_tr_head.addView(select_head);// add the column to
                                                        // the
        // table row here
        select_head.setTextSize(20);

        // select checkbox
        final CheckBox customer_checkbox = new CheckBox(this);
        customer_checkbox.setId(20);
        customer_checkbox.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        customer_checkbox.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        customer_checkbox.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 12);
        customer_checkbox.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.checkbox_selector);
        supplier_details_tr_head.addView(customer_checkbox);

        first_calendar_table.addView(supplier_details_tr_head,
                new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        // ---------------Calendar Table
        // Header-----------------------------------------------

        // ----------------------On click imageView

        imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                if(showingFirst == true){
                    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.opened_icon);
                    showingFirst = false;
                }else{
                    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.closed_icon);
                    imageView.setTag(70);
                    showingFirst = true;
                }

            }
        });
        // ----------------------On click customer_name
    }

    // method to show toast message
        public void makeAToast(String str) {
            // yet to implement
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
            toast.show();
        }
}
```

**The layout file:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="3dp"
    tools:context=".CalendarActivity" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/CalendarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="#FFFFFF" >

            <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/first_calendar_table"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >
            </TableLayout>

            <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/second_calendar_table"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/first_calendar_table"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >
            </TableLayout>

            <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/third_calendar_table"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/second_calendar_table"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >
            </TableLayout>

            <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/fourth_calendar_table"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/third_calendar_table"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >
            </TableLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

What should I do to achieve my goal?

Comment: use `center_vertical` in the layout...

Comment: at parent layout of imageview

Comment: use <b>center_vertical </b> in the layout in TableLayout..

Comment: no effect on the output